# How to authenticate with GitHub to install private Maven packages in CircleCI?

Tags: maven, circleci, github-package-registry

My Maven web application uses several JAR dependencies hosted as private GitHub packages.  I'm trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline with CircleCI.

When CircleCI tries to build with mvn package, it fails with a 401 when attempting to install the private packages.  I don't know how to approach authenticating.  I've added SSH deploy and user keys to the project settings, but that doesn't seem to help Maven.  I know that locally, I added a server tag with my personal access token to the .m2/conf/settings.xml file to authenticate.  But what should I do within CircleCI?  Googling hasn't revealed anything.

Update: I included settings.xml with a hardcoded access token within the repository and included `-gs ./settings.xml` in my maven build command to point to it.  Works but doubt this is best practice, so leaving the question open.

Comment: An option is to create a dedicated CI user account.